# CSV file containing phonetic letters trying to encode with UTF-8 in Android/Java

Tags: android, encoding, csv, utf-8

I have an Android- as well as iPhone-Version of my App. In iOS I can tell the CSV-Parser to encode the string with UTF-8. Apparently this is also possible in Android when I use the InputStreamReader when I open the CSV file.

```
isr = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(
                    "english.csv"), "UTF-8");
```

Also when I check the encoding

```
System.out.println(isr.getEncoding());
```

it returns UTF8.

The weird thing now is, that some phonetic words!! are shown completely correct, whereas most of them show phonetic words containing square symbols. Although the exact same letters are shown correctly in other words.

Comment: I've found a solution. I will post it as soon as I'm able to

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys,

apparently it only works with applying another font. Because the encoding really works. Only Android standard fonts have their problem displaying phonetic letters.

I followed this guy's solution:

[I don't use unicode characters in my android-textview.How can I do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108876/i-dont-use-unicode-characters-in-my-android-textview-how-can-i-do-this)

and used another font called Constructium. Just have to import it into your assets folder and use it either through the XML Layout file or directly in your code, as this guy has done it:

[How to change the font on the TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888508/how-to-change-the-font-on-the-text-view-in-android)